# Extracting integer from int_Ring type in mathcomp's ssralg

Tags: coq, ssreflect

A bit of set up for the question: The notation `` `_i `` is defined to be the i-th component of a sequence, but is also meant to be the i-th coefficient of a polynomial. The following code outputs `Negz 2 : int_ZmodType`:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.
From mathcomp Require Import all_algebra.
Open Scope ring_scope.
Definition my_seq := [:: Posz 4; Negz 2].
Eval compute in my_seq`_1.
```

The type of `my_seq` is `seq int`. The type `int` has constructors `Posz` and `Negz`.

The header of
https://github.com/math-comp/math-comp/blob/master/mathcomp/algebra/poly.v
informs us that `Poly s` is a polynomial with coefficients from the sequence `s`. It also says that `` p`_i `` is the i-th coefficient of a polynomial `p`. I expected the following code to output `Negz 2`:

```
Definition my_polynomial := Poly my_seq.
Eval compute in my_polynomial`_1.
```

The resulting term is not `Negz 2`, though it does have type `int_Ring`. There is a sequence constructor `polyseq` for polynomials. Indeed, the type of `polyseq my_polynomial` is `seq int_Ring`. However, doing `` Eval compute in (polyseq my_polynomial)`_1. `` gives the same mess.

In transitioning from the concrete type `int` to `int_Ring`, has the value of the integer been lost? Or, is there a way to recover the value of an `int` from an `int_Ring`? The way `int_Ring` is packaged, it doesn't look like it's possible, because the constructors don't reference elements. However, the same can be said of `int_ZmodType`. For reference, those types are defined in

https://github.com/math-comp/math-comp/blob/master/mathcomp/algebra/ssralg.v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version of your code that works:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.
From mathcomp Require Import all_algebra.
Open Scope ring_scope.
Definition my_seq := [:: Posz 4; Negz 2].
Definition my_poly := @Polynomial _ my_seq erefl.
Compute my_poly`_1.
```

Instead of using the simpler `Poly` wrapper function defined in the library, this version calls directly the constructor of `polynomial`.  If you look at the definition of this type, you'll see that a polynomial is simply a record containing the sequence of coefficients of the polynomial, plus a proof of a boolean equality asserting that the last element of this sequence (the leading coefficient) is not zero.  (The second argument in the above expression is a proof that `true = true`, which is understood by Coq as the same thing as a proof of `(last 1 polyseq != 0) = true`, by the rules of computation.) You can check manually that there is nothing preventing the expression we're computing from reducing, so Coq is able to figure out the answer.

To see what is wrong with your original attempt, we have to unfold it a little bit.  I have included the relevant definitions here in order, expanding some notations:

```
Poly s := foldr cons_poly (polyC 0)

polyC c := insubd poly_nil [:: c]

(* from eqtype.v *)
insubd {T : Type} {P : pred T} {sT : subType T P} u0 (x : T) : sT := 
  odflt u0 (insub x)

insub {T : Type} {P : pred T} {sT : subType T P} (x : T) : option sT 
  := if @idP (P x) is ReflectT Px then @Some sT (Sub x Px) else None
```

And here we find the culprit: `Poly` is defined in terms of `insub`, which in turn is defined by case analysis on `idP`, which is an opaque lemma! And Coq's reduction gets stuck when an opaque term gets in the way. (In case you are curious, what is going on here is that `insub` is testing, using `idP`, whether the leading coefficient of the polynomial is indeed different from zero, and, if so, using that fact to build the polynomial.)

The problem is that many definitions in ssreflect were not made to compute fully inside the logic. This is due to two reasons. One is performance: by allowing everything to fully reduce, we can make type checking much slower. The other is that ssreflect is tailored for convenience of reasoning, so many definitions are not the most efficient. The [CoqEAL](https://github.com/CoqEAL/CoqEAL) library was developed to connect definitions with better computational behavior to ones that are easier to reason about, like in ssreflect; unfortunately, I don't know if the project is still being maintained.

Comment: Thank you for another great answer! I traced the definitions as far as possible, but didn't know that I should be looking for opacity as a culprit for computation. Good to know.

Answer (score 3):

This is not completely answering the question, but I managed to prove that the coefficient is indeed `Negz 2`. I give the proof here for the record. Note that I am not familiar at all with ssreflect, so there may be better and more natural ways to do this.

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.
From mathcomp Require Import all_algebra.
Open Scope ring_scope.
Definition my_seq := [:: Posz 4; Negz 2].
Eval compute in my_seq`_1.

Definition my_polynomial := Poly my_seq.

Example test : my_polynomial `_1 = Negz 2.
Proof.
  cbn.
  rewrite 2!polyseq_cons. cbn.
  rewrite 2!size_polyC. cbn.
  rewrite polyseqC. cbn. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

EDIT: As explained in the comments below, there exist simpler proofs of this fact.

Comment: You can also do `by rewrite /my_polynomial (@PolyK _ 1).`.

Comment: Indeed, much simpler.

Comment: Thank you - not quite what I was looking for, but interesting nonetheless. I considered including in the question the fact that poly.v (line 246) has a proof script for `(Poly s) \`_i = s \`_i` and that this was not what I was looking for. Ideally, one could construct polynomials from sequences, add and multiply, and then extract coefficients via polyseq. (But, add and multiply for polynomials also uses opaque terms!) As Arthur mentions, the strength of the library is reasoning, so I should probably be looking elsewhere for computation needs.

Comment: I did not check before writing this comment, but you should probably look at the [CoqEAL library](https://github.com/CoqEAL/CoqEAL).